# Mac's Menu bar's sub class not working as in Lunx and Windows

Tags: linux, macos, qt

I'd like to run a qt code from linux to Mac pc, I subclass a QMenu, to implment a functionality like, when selecting a sub menu's option, it doesn't close the top level's menu. 
And the code working in Linux, but it doesn't work in Mac OS, is it linked to the Mac's menu bar moved to the system's menu, that its behavior not the same?

the related part of code:

```
void MySubMenu::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
{
QAction *action = activeAction();
    if (action && action->isEnabled()) {  
        action->setEnabled(false);
        QMenu::mouseReleaseEvent(e);
        action->setEnabled(true);
        action->trigger();
    }
    else
        QMenu::mouseReleaseEvent(e);
}
```

When I debug above code,adding trace in the blocks, I find that, in env Mac when mouse clicking on menus bar's option, this mouseReleaseEvent() has never been entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac menus are not handled by Qt, they are handled by native code and Qt doesn't get notified of anything happening there. The menu bar is a shared system resource, IIRC. You can't override it's behavior - even if you could, it'd make your application feel out-of-place. Don't do it, that's all.